# How to check if IQueryable element/ item contains a property in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IQueryable` as follows

```
var issues = from i in jira.Issues.Queryable
             where i.Project == project.Key
             orderby i.Created
             select i;
```

I am trying to get the count where issue type is `Bug` like this:

```
TotalIssues = issues.ToList().Where(i => i.Type.Name == "Bug").Count();
```

The problem here is there are some issues without a type. How can I check if the issue type exists?

Comment: Side note: `ToList()` is redundant here, `AsEnumerable()` will be enough

Comment: Try *null propagartion*: `.Where(item => item?.Type?.Name == "Bug")` in order to have `null` if `item` or `item.Type` are `null`

Comment: Hi @DmitryBychenko I get Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" after adding "?"

Answer (score 3):

You don't want issues without type. You can keep code simple by not taking issues without type into account.

```
var bugsCount = issues.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(issue => issue.Type != null)
    .Count(issue => issue.Type.Name == "Bug");
```

You can chain as much `.Where` clauses as you wish, items will be still enumerated only once.

Answer (score 2):

You can try *null propagation* `?.` in order to have `null` for `Name` if any `item` or `item.Type` are `null`:

```
TotalIssues = issues
  .AsEnumerable() // Linq to objects from now on; no need in materialization
  .Count(item => "Bug".Equals(item?.Type?.Name)); // just count
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean? Some issues don't have Type Property? Or Some issues's property Type is null?

If it is some issues don't have Type Property, I think you can specify issues's class or interface. Or you can use reflection.

If it is some issues's property Type is null, you can check Type is not null first.
From your comment, I think i may be null too.

```
i!=null && i.Type!=null && i.Type.Name=="Bug"
```

Comment: I tried this didn't work I get reference is not set to an instance error

Comment: It seems that, not i.Type is null, but i is null.